# C# Entity Framework : update EDMX from model error 'EntityCommandExecutionException'

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio, entity-framework

When I try to update my `.EDMX` with update model from database, I get the following error:

> Query processor could not produce a query plan because of the hints defined in this query. Resubmit the query without specifying any hints and without using SET FORCEPLAN

Any help would be much appreciated.

We have multiple databases, I have tried connecting to all of these and still get the same error.

I have tried starting a new project and still get the same error.

Comment: What is the framework and version of your app?

Comment: We are using Entity Framework 6.2.0 and our .Net Framework is 4.8

Comment: Is it possible to convert your .edmx to a dbcontext?

Comment: We have also tried updateing to the latest Entity Framework version but still the same.

Comment: If you are on about changing it to a EF core project we dont really want to do it at this point.

Comment: Need to check from my end.

Comment: Are you getting the error locally or in azure?

Comment: @CiarenT, what did you do before you update .edmx file? Could you please provide at least one database design? It will be better for me to analyze your problem.

Comment: ABSOLUTELY same here! After years of model generating/refreshing from Azure I got this error today! What is going on?

Comment: @Harshitha The only error we are getting locally is the one i provided above. There is no error in azure.

Comment: @Shockwaver thats the exact same here, no problems for years and even the beginning of this week, but then it just stopped working.

Comment: I found another hit on reddit from few hrs ago! I suspect this is general and related to some hot-patch MS released on Azure SQL Server lately... https://www.reddit.com/r/csharp/comments/16v1lp6/visual_studio_error/

Comment: Well, to confirm that, I exported the data-tier and imported it locally. Update-refreshing it from local gave absolutely no problems at all. What happened to Azure SQL Server?
@Harshitha The error comes only from connecting to Azure instances, as I said when the same schema is accessed locally EF throws no error

Comment: @CiarenT - Once check your Indexes on the DB.

Comment: @Harshitha We have checked them and there all fine. There has not been any new indexes added fo some time. As i say we have many DB's all with different data in and no matter which one we try use we still get the same error.

Comment: I confirm multiple instances on Azure having the same issue, but upon importing the data-tier locally the EDMX generation does work flawlessly on local (SQL Server 15.0.2101.7)

Comment: Not to just keep saying "same" but I suggest everyone with this issue gets onto Microsoft via the azure portal to reference this post and the reddit post. But yes, 6 years of zero issues and now we're getting this problem with Azure SQL databases only. Has anyone else noticed degraded query performance this week also? I'm seeing significant issues with proc performance seems to be caused by execution plan storage. ALTER proc is fixing the issue temporarily but there's no fixing this EDMX issue. Execution fails after 600ms and the query is too big to extract from the Azure Exection Logs.

Comment: @Richard It's rolling already
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Cannot-update-EF6-EDMX-Model-for-databas/10480914

Comment: I'm the same. I made a copy of the project and removed all tables etc from the EDMX. Made no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Please up vote for fix:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Cannot-update-EF6-EDMX-Model-for-databas/10480914?q=edmx&stateGroup=active

Regards,
Graham

Answer (score 0):

Not an ideal solution until Microsoft fix whatever update they made to their Azure databases - but as a temporary work-around - you can copy your database schema to a local database on a local server and generate your EDMX model using that database while leaving your connection string on your application to the Azure database.

Entity framework will still perform it's CRUD functionality on Azure - the issue is just for modelling the database in it's EDMX model from an Azure database.

UPDATE: Microsoft have fixed the issue. You can use Azure Databases again for EDMX modelling

Comment: We have set up replication to UK west which doesnt seem to have the problem. Its costly but works as a work around for the time being.

Comment: @CiarenT Haven't tried a UK West server yet - ours are set to UK South. But I guess my answer is a cost efficient solution at least. Thankfully just the schemas are required to update the EDMX

Comment: Agreed, we have just set it up temporarily untill they sort the actually issue out.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it looks like the situation reverted back to normal. EDMX generation is now successful again.

Comment: Agreed, tried this morning and all looks to be good now.